# $Lookup and $addField in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have the following two collections and I want to be able to join them and output the number total number of games played by player A and player B.

```
profiles collection
[
   {
     name: 'A'
     player_id: 1
   },
   {
    name: 'B'
    player_id: 2
  }
  {
    name: 'C'
    player_id: 3
   }
 ]


games collection
    [
       {
         game_id: 1
         player_id: 1
       },
       {
        name: 2
        player_id: 2
      },
    {
       game_id: 3
       player_id: 1
    },
    {
       name: 4
       player_id: 2
     }
    {
       name: 5
       player_id: 3
     }
  ]
```

Now the goal is the output the total number of games played by player A and B but not C when I am given their names but not ID. So the following SQL Statement:

```
    SELECT * FROM (results for A) UNION (results for B);
```

So I am using lookup to combine the collections like this:

```
  db.games.aggregate([
   {
     '$lookup':
       {
         from: "profiles",
         localField: "player_id",
         foreignField: "player_id",
         as: "player"
       }
  },
       {
        "$addFields": {
            "player": {
                        "$filter": {
                            "input": "$player",
                            "as": "p",
                            "cond": {
                                "$eq": [ "$$p.name", "A" ]
                            }
                        }
            }
        }
    },
  ])
```

When I just do lookup it creates a 'player' field that contains the information of that player using player_id but when I add 'addField', player comes out empty.

Comment: Can you share your desired result?

Answer (score 0):

To find the total number of games played by player A and B. so you can try as below:

```
db.games.aggregate([
   {
     '$lookup':
       {
         from: "profile",
         localField: "player_id",
         foreignField: "player_id",
         as: "player"
       }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            'player.name': { $in: ['A','B']}
        }  
    },    
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            total: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    }
  ])
```